How to make a searchable signleSelect type column using DataGrid
I have a singleSelect type column, because the list is really long (contains 170 items), I’d like to make it searchable. Basically, when the dropdown list is open, I want to be able to type in the word, then if that value is in the list, the list will jump down to that value and select it. How to implement this?
Do I need to make a custom component that combines a dropdown list and an autocompletion component?
Here is what feeds into the dropdown list, and other related code. All pretty standard, nothing fancy
const Challenges = (props) => {
   const [….] = props;
   const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
    …

    useEffect(() => {
        let rows = [];
        …

        Object.entries(editingChallenges).map(([key, data]) => {
            data.id = key;
            rows.push(data);
        });
        setRows(rows);
    },[]);

    const buildGameNameSelector = (machineId) => {
        let allGames = [];

        allGames.push({ value: 1, label: '' });

        Object.entries(activeMachines).map(([key, name]) => {
            allGames.push({ value: key, label: name + ' (' + key + ')' });
        });

        return allGames;
    }
 
    const columns= [
        { ...   },
        { field: 'machine_id', headerName: 'Game', width: 300, editable: true, type: 'singleSelect', valueOptions: buildGameNameSelector() },
        …
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            …

                <Box
                    sx={{
                        height: 500,
                        width: '100%',
                        '& .actions': {
                            color: 'text.secondary',
                        },
                        '& .textPrimary': {
                            color: 'text.primary',
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    <DataGrid
                        rows={rows}
                        columns={columns}
                        processRowUpdate={(updatedRow, originalRow) => processRowUpdate(updatedRow)}
                        onProcessRowUpdateError={() => handleProcessRowUpdateError}
                    />
                </Box>
        </div>
    );
}


I’m new to DataGrid, so nay help would be greatly appreciated!
